# Cant plot an equation properly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a 3rd rank polynomial that I calculated through Lagrance with a given set of x,y.(x=P_Maz , y=H_Maz).I can't really find what I am doing wrong.Even some plots I tried would show me wrong graph(Because x=0 wouldnt give y=25).
The equation is as follows:

```
           3            2
3.395e-06 x - 0.001528 x + 1.976 x + 25
```

The part of my function and plot is this one:

```
P_Maz = np.array([120, 180, 270, 300])  # x
H_Maz = np.array([246, 351, 514, 572])  # y

def Lagrange(Lx, Ly):
    x = symbols('x')
    y = 0
    for k in range(len(Lx)):
        p = 1
        for j in range(len(Lx)):
            if j != k:
                p = p * ((x - Lx[j]) / (Lx[k] - Lx[j]))
        y += p * Ly[k]
    return y

poly1=simplify(Lagrange(P_Maz,H_Maz))

plot(P_Maz,poly1(H_Maz))
grid()
show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Egw\Desktop\Analysh\Askhsh1\askhsh5.py", line 36, in <module>
    plot(P_Maz,poly1(H_Maz))
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Full code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, grid
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
from sympy import symbols, Eq,simplify

P_Maz = np.array([120, 180, 270, 300])  # x
H_Maz = np.array([246, 351, 514, 572])  # y
P_Lig = np.array([150, 215, 285, 300])  # x
H_Lig = np.array([307, 427, 563, 594])  # y


def Lagrange(Lx, Ly):
    x = symbols('x')
    y = 0
    for k in range(len(Lx)):
        p = 1
        for j in range(len(Lx)):
            if j != k:
                p = p * ((x - Lx[j]) / (Lx[k] - Lx[j]))
        y += p * Ly[k]
    return y

poly1=simplify(Lagrange(P_Maz,H_Maz))
poly2=simplify(Lagrange(P_Lig,H_Lig))

print(Lagrange(P_Maz, H_Maz)) #Morfh Klasmatwn
print(poly1) #Telikh eksiswsh
print(lagrange(P_Maz,H_Maz)) #Telikh eksiswsh me built in method

print(Lagrange(P_Lig, H_Lig)) #Morfh Klasmatwn
print(poly2) #Telikh eksiswsh
print(lagrange(P_Lig,H_Lig)) #Telikh eksiswsh me built in method

plot(P_Maz,poly1(P_Maz))
grid()
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `simplify`, you get an expression, but then you need to evaluate that expression for all the desired values.

You can do that through `lambdify`:

```
from sympy import lambdify

f = lambdify(x, simplify(Lagrange(P_Maz,H_Maz)), "numpy") 
# above, just copied your simplify call with your variables and used in the lambdify

plot(P_Maz, f(P_Maz)) # use the created lambdify function, f, not the unevaluated expression
```

Mind the warning in the documentation ([docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html)): "lambdify uses eval. Don’t use it on unsanitized input."

Comment: Shouldn't it be plot(P_Maz,f(P_Maz)) since P_Maz=x values?Also I tried with lambdify and still get the wrong graph compared to the correct one.

Comment: Yes, P_Maz. I didnt copy correctly. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately,it still does't give the correct plot as expected.I expect this plot https://prnt.sc/RSTn1F8E9Gyk but instead get this plot https://prnt.sc/9NDHf8PNJTk3

Comment: You need to plot the desired x range (you are currently plotting 120 to 300). Furthermore, the equation you obtained, around 0, is dominated by the degree-1 and degree-0 terms (look at the coefficients), so it is nearly linear. Maybe the maths are not correctly implemented.

Comment: Isn't the plot function supposed to work by giving it x values and according to the f(x) to give u the proper graph? For example:plot(x,f(x)) supposed to give you the graph that you want?

Comment: Turns out,I made a mistake on my part.Your suggestion regardless was correct and I have made the plot correct thanks to that.So thank you.